# Proper way for Indexing sorted data in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, indexing

There is a sorted list containing dictionary elements in Python of length 1000 like given below

```
[
 {'date': '2017-05-20', 'category': 'create', 'data': 23}, 
 {'date':'2017-05-21', 'category': 'use', 'data': 1}, 
 {'date': '2017-05-23', 'category': 'create', 'data': 4},
]
```

Each element of list contains dictionary with fields

1. date
2. category
3. data

List is sorted by date of dictionary element.

---

Problem is there are two type of functions operating on list based on

- date in sorted order of list(that's why data is sorted by date in list)
- category of data

So, I have to traverse the complete list for operating on single category many times.

---

One solution I came up with is maintaining a dictionary with key as category and value as indexes in sorted list.

```
index = {'create': [0, 2], 'use': [1]}
```

I want to know what is the best or pythonic way to achieve this functionality? Or If there is any data structure like this.

Comment: If the size is small enough a list of indexes is a pretty nice way. If the size of the list or the complexity of searches increases, you could be interested in converting the sorted list into a SQLite table and use SQL queries on it.

Comment: Thanks Serge, then I will go with above approach until I found other better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is good. You can even define a generator function which takes a category as input as below

```
def list_by_category(category, original_list):
  for entry in original_list:
    if entry['category'] == category:
      yield entry
```

usage:

```
# Do something with 'create':
for entry in list_by_category('create'):
  print entry
  # Do things here..
```

.

This way you can avoid memory overhead of maintaining another list for each category.

Comment: But @gipsy, I don't want to traverse complete list for each category. That is the problem in first place.

Comment: Yeah, then your indexing idea make more sense.

Comment: I am wondering is there any pythonic solution to this problem.

Comment: You can make use of a defaultdict to make the indexing little cleaner. I've added a new answer take a look

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to create 2 additional dictionaries with keys represented by record index in the list for category `create` and `use`.

For example:

```
create_dict = {0: {'date': '2017-05-20', 'category': 'create', 'data': 23},
               2: {'date': '2017-05-23', 'category': 'create', 'data': 4}}

use_dict = {1: {'date':'2017-05-21', 'category': 'use', 'data': 1}}
```

However, the assumption is that the indexes in the original list do not change.

If the date field in the original list is also unique you can create a similar dict where keys will be dates. Using dictionaries you can quickly (O(1)) access all the element by the key. The downside is the memory usage if you deal with really big dictionaries.

Comment: when I have to operate on dates then I have to do lot overhead calculations for making dates sorted. No, dates are not unique in original list.

Comment: @infiQuanta, then use the indexes as keys in the additional dictionaries if they don't change.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
original_list = [
 {'date': '2017-05-20', 'category': 'create', 'data': 23}, 
 {'date':'2017-05-21', 'category': 'use', 'data': 1}, 
 {'date': '2017-05-23', 'category': 'create', 'data': 4},
]

# indexing 

category_index = defaultdict(list)
for idx, entry in enumerate(original_list):
  category_index[entry['category']].append(idx)


# using the index:

# Working with 'create'

for idx in category_index['create']:
  print original_list[idx]
  # Do things with entry

# Working with 'use'

for idx in category_index['use']:
  print original_list[idx]
  # Do things with entry
```

Comment: In this way we are duplicating complete list again. I think its waste of memory.

Comment: if space is a concern just append the index instead of the entry itself.

Comment: updated my answer to just store the list indexes in the category_index

Comment: Yeah, this is what I am doing and posted this solution above in problem statement. But, Thanks.